# Is using words which denote a specific time with present perfect tense grammatically correct?

Tags: present-perfect

**"We have seen many such cases now".**

Now,as far as I know,present perfect tense is never used alongside words which denote a specific time like now, yesterday, tonight, today etc.

So, is it like this sentence is grammatically correct in certain cases or this is an informal way of putting it ?

Comment: I think this sentence would be correct if "by now" had been used instead of simply "now".

Comment: I wouldn't say 'never used'. _I have finished [the job] now_ is a perfectly acceptable way to say 'At the present moment, the task has just been completed'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a secondary meaning of the word 'now'. You'll find it in the Cambridge dictionary after the most common meaning, which is of course the present time.

'Now' can also be used to *express how long something has been happening, from when it began to the present time*.

This is exactly what it means in your example - that they have seen a lot of cases from a fixed point in the past *until now*.